# Learning Aderet Eliyahu

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, adult-learning, vilna-gaon

Anyone know of any resources online to help one learn "aderet Eliyahu" (the vilna gaon's commentary on the Torah) - an online shiur perhaps?

Comment: I don't have any shiurim, but daat has a very clean copy of the text in PDF format if you want: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=150